# SQL Monthly reports also showing even in different year

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the monthly reports of visitors from my database where I have a datetime picker that only display month and year (MM/yyyy) The code is working but the problem is it also works even in different year.

```
var FirstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(dtpMonth.Value.Year, dtpMonth.Value.Month, 1);
var LastDayOfMonth = FirstDayOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Male),0) as Male,ISNULL(SUM(Female),0)  as Female ,ISNULL(SUM(Pax),0)  as Pax,ISNULL(SUM(Single),0)  as Single,ISNULL(SUM(Married),0)  as Married,ISNULL(SUM(Students),0)  as Students,ISNULL(SUM(Elementary),0)  as Elementary,ISNULL(SUM(Highschool),0)  as Highschool, ISNULL(SUM(College),0)  as College,ISNULL(SUM(PWD),0)  as PWD, ISNULL(SUM([AR Users]),0)  as ARUsers,ISNULL(SUM([12 Below]),0)  as age1,ISNULL(SUM([13-21]),0)  as age2,ISNULL(SUM([22-35]),0)  as age3,ISNULL(SUM([36-50]),0)  as age4,ISNULL(SUM([51-65]),0)  as age5,ISNULL(SUM([65 Above]),0)  as age6 FROM  [tbl_Registration] where [Date Added] BETWEEN '"
        + FirstDayOfMonth.ToShortDateString() + "' AND  '" + LastDayOfMonth.ToShortDateString() + "'  ;", connection);
```

**PROBLEM**

IF I CHANGE THE YEAR TO 09/2017 THE OUTPUT IS THE SAME AS 09/2018.
I am clearing the labels before loading data so its not the issue.

[image: 2018]
[image: 2017]

Comment: Debug the application to determine which exactly code is sent to db.

Comment: Use a parameterized query with strongly-typed date parameters instead of passing strings. That will avoid problems with regional settings.

Comment: Ive also query it in db and i got the same results. I think the problem is my query

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
I am so dumb! I the data type of the Date is in varchar.